# Wordpress error PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) when I'm trying to install, update a plugin, but the error is solved temporarily if I restart the server

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, tmp

Whenever I try to install or update a wordpress plugin, I get this error:

```
PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4)
```

This is also happening if I edit a template from a layout manager or if I do anything that depends on the `/tmp` folder.

If I restart Apache, the problem is solved, but only temporarily. After a few minutes to one hour it looks like the access to the `/tmp` folder is restricted by Apache again.

I also created a custom `/tmp` folder inside Wordpress content folder, with 755 permission, and settled it in the configuration file, even so I still get the same problem.

Running Apache on CentOS8, using Direct Admin control panel.

Comment: Apache does not start changing access to folders after a few minutes or hours. My guess is you are running low on disk space.

Comment: Disk used is 6Gb out of 34Gb.